# MINGW32 error, using wrong version of ruby and fixing alias for sublime text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mingw32

I had Ruby 1.9.2 installed on my computer in `C:\program files x86` folder. I installed RailsInstaller which put Ruby 1.9.3 in `C:\RailsInstaller`. I uninstalled 1.9.2 using Control Panel.

When I run commands in `cmd.exe`, ruby 1.9.3 is applied, everything works fine. However, when I run commands in `MINGW32`, Ruby 1.9.2 is applied and I get errors. "`C:/Program:` bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

However, if I do ruby -v in MINGW32, It says I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

How do I make MINGW32 use the Ruby version installed with RailsInstaller?

my `.bashrc` file only has this line:

alias subl="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe

That alias setup also does not work.

Using Windows 8 Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. open c:/msys/1.0/etc/profile (suppose MSYS is install according your MinGW).
2. find the `export PATH=".:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:$PATH"`
3. Modify it as `export PATH=".:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/RailsInstaller:$PATH`
4. save and restart MSYS.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue, I checked the PATH variable from Environmental variables, it had Ruby 1.9.2, so I was able to change that to point to C:\RailsInstaller, and everything worked fine!

Thanks for the help, editing the PATH variable reminded me to check the other PATH one.